# Circuits and formulas for Clique

Tags: complexity-theory, logic, propositional-logic

Is it correct to say that the Clique Problem is in $P$ iff there exists a family of Boolean circuits $C$ to decide Clique whose sizes are bounded by a polynomial? And based on [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/121243/relationship-between-circuit-size-and-formula-size-in-sipser-text), does that imply that there exists an equivalent set of Boolean formulas $F$ to decide Clique whose sizes are bounded by a polynomial? And if there is such an $F$, would there be correct derivations based on propositional logic axioms from any member of $F$ to the corresponding [large naive formula for Clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Circuit_complexity)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that the answer to all your questions is false:

- There are languages decided by constant size circuits which aren't decidable.
- It is conjectured that $\mathsf{NC^1} \neq \mathsf{P}$.
- It is conjectured that $\mathsf{NP} \neq \mathsf{coNP}$.